# IF in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

If I do (MyVar is set to "hi" value)

```
IF %MyVar% == "hi" ( Echo Hi )
```

Then I got Output

```
Hi
```

But If I do ( ProgramFile(x86) is set to C:\Program Files (x86))

```
IF %ProgramFiles(x86)% == "C:\Program Files (x86)" ( Echo Hi )
```

then I got Out put

```
Files was unexpected at this time.
```

If I do:

```
 IF "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "C:\Program Files (x86)" ( Echo Hi )
```

Then I got **NO** output

Why output is not coming properly in case of ProgramFile(x86) environment variable?

Comment: what does `set ProgramFiles(x86)` say?

Comment: Unable to re-create.  `IF "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "C:\Program Files (x86)" ( Echo Hi )` echoes Hi on my machine.  Your lack of output was probably the result of a typo.  Why not just do `if defined PROGRAMFILES(x86) echo Hi` instead?

Comment: @Stephan set ProgramFiles(x86) gives output   C:\Program Files (x86)

Comment: @ shA.t & @rojo :   **`if defined PROGRAMFILES(x86) echo Hi`** and **`IF /I "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" equ "C:\Program Files (x86)" (echo Hi)`** are working fine but when I use **==** operator for compare, it gives  `Files was unexpected at this time.` output

Comment: That's because you didn't enclose the variable in quotation marks.  Its value contains a space.

Comment: @rojo I did `IF %ProgramFiles(x86)% == "C:\Program Files (x86)" ( Echo Hi )`  which is fine

Comment: No it isn't.  It should be `IF "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "C:\Program Files (x86)" ( Echo Hi )`

Answer (score 1):

`If` Command Extensions are enabled IF changes as follows:

- `IF [/I] string1 compare-op string2 command`
- `IF CMDEXTVERSION number command`
- `IF DEFINED variable command`

where `compare-op` may be one of:

```
EQU - equal
NEQ - not equal
LSS - less than
LEQ - less than or equal
GTR - greater than
GEQ - greater than or equal
```

and the `/I` switch, if specified, says to do case insensitive string compares. The `/I` switch can also be used on the `string1==string2` form of IF. These comparisons are generic, in that if both string1 and string2 are both comprised of all numeric digits, then the strings are converted to numbers and a numeric comparison is performed.

> using `compare-op` with `/I` can be better;

so you can try this code:

```
IF /I "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" equ "C:\Program Files (x86)" (echo Hi)
```

> But maybe the commend text is invalid:

The CMDEXTVERSION conditional works just like ERRORLEVEL, except it is comparing against an internal version number associated with the Command Extensions. The first version is 1. It will be incremented by one when significant enhancements are added to the Command Extensions. CMDEXTVERSION conditional is never true when Command Extensions are disabled.

Comment: Try this `IF %ProgramFiles(x86)% equ %ProgramFiles(x86)% (echo hi)` !